# Using a data member of the derived class in a requires clause of the base CRTP class

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to implement a sort of static polymorphism by means of the CRTP and `requires` clauses.

What I want to achieve is to call a possibly overriden function in a function taking a reference to the CRTP base class.

I made it work with GCC 10 and 11 with the following approach:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
  void f() const requires T::IsOverridden
    { static_cast<T const *>(this)->f(); }

  void f() const
    { std::cout << "Fallback f()" << std::endl; }
};

class A : public Base<A>
{
public:
  static constexpr bool IsOverridden = true;

public:
  void f() const
    { std::cout << "Overridden f()" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public Base<B> {};

template<typename T>
void f(Base<T> const &x)
  { x.f(); }

int main()
{
  A const a;
  B const b;

  f(a);
  f(b);

  return 0;
}
```

However, Clang 11 doesn't like this piece of Code:

```
test.cpp:7:30: error: no member named 'IsOverridden' in 'A'
  void f() const requires T::IsOverridden
                          ~~~^
test.cpp:14:18: note: in instantiation of template class 'Base<A>' requested here
class A : public Base<A>
                 ^
test.cpp:7:30: error: no member named 'IsOverridden' in 'B'
  void f() const requires T::IsOverridden
                          ~~~^
test.cpp:24:18: note: in instantiation of template class 'Base<B>' requested here
class B : public Base<B> {};
                 ^
```

Which compiler is right?

Note: I'm using a boolean member to signal overriding because I want it to work with classes nested in template classes and that was the only way I came up with in that case.

Comment: Issue with CRTP is that `Derived` is an incomplete type inside `Base<Derived>` definition (and normally complete **inside** member definition). Clang seems right.

Comment: As alternative, you might use `if constexpr` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b62a673d116732a1).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. Another workaround, accepted by Clang: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ki8pshYJpmVYzSQx. Is Clang right at instantiating functions with trailing requires clauses when the class is instantiated? I've also tested MSVC and agrees with G++.

Comment: it doesn't instantiate the function, but the class and can so checks signatures and template function for non-dependent (in regard to function template agument, as template class argument is now fixed) stuff.

Comment: @Jarod42 Clang bug. See this comment by Richard Smith: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44833#c4. (Thanks to PilarLatiesa for pointing this out).

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting what I ended up using in case it is useful for somebody else.

I didn't like using a member variable, which I could easily misspell, to signal that the function was overridden.

Instead I used a defaulted `std::false_type` NTTP for the base-class function, and a `std::true_type` NTTP for the overloads, so that they can be detected with a requires-expression:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
  template<std::false_type = std::false_type{}>
    requires requires(T const x) { x.template f<std::true_type{}>(); }
  void f() const
    { static_cast<T const *>(this)->f(); }

  template<std::false_type = std::false_type{}>
  void f() const
    { std::cout << "Fallback f()" << std::endl; }
};

class A : public Base<A>
{
public:
  template<std::true_type = std::true_type{}>
  void f() const
    { std::cout << "Overridden f()" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public Base<B> {};

template<typename T>
void f(Base<T> const &x)
  { x.f(); }

int main()
{
  A const a;
  B const b;

  f(a);
  f(b);

  return 0;
}
```

GCC 11 accepts the terser syntax `template<std::true_type = {}>`, but GCC 10 and CLang 12 require the longer `template<std::true_type = std::true_type{}>`.

Comment: Your approach requires a tweak to work with Clang. Filed: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50137